# Reference for a nice proof of "undetermined coefficients"

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, reference-request, mathematics-education, alternative-proof, differential-equations

I'm teaching an honors differential equations class and have been using linear algebra heavily.  I thought it would be interesting to include a proof of the method of undetermined coefficients along the lines described below, which I figured is already known.  Nonetheless, Google turns up no proof other than the obvious one by integration, which is significantly messier and uses no linear algebra, so perhaps I'm wrong.

> What is the (standard, best, earliest) reference to the following proof?

Note: I have made a conscious decision not to ask this on math.stackexchange since, based on my last question asking about a reference there, I don't think it will even be noticed.

**Theorem:** Let $L$ be a constant-coefficient $n$th order linear differential operator with characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)$, and let $y(t) = t^m e^{qt}$ for some integer $m \geq 0$ and $q \in \mathbb{C}$.  Suppose that $q$ is a $k$-fold root of $p(\lambda)$.  Then the equation $Lx = y$ has a solution of the form $t^k f(t) e^{qt}$, where $f(t)$ is a polynomial of degree $m$.

**Proof outline:**

1. $y$ is a solution of the equation $L_2 y = 0$, where $L_2 = (\tfrac{d}{dt} - q)^m$.  The pair of equations $Lx = y, L_2 y = 0$ can be written as a system of $n + m + 1$ first-order equations via the linear transformation $\vec{z} = (x, x', \dots, x^{(n - 1)}, y, y', \dots, y^{(m)})$, for which the coefficient matrix is:
   $$M = \left(\begin{array}{c|c}
   A & \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & & \vdots \\ 1 & \cdots & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \\ \hline
   0 & C
   \end{array}\right)$$
   where $A$ is the companion matrix of $L$ and $C$ is the companion matrix of $L_2$.
2. It is easily verified that:

   - The eigenvalues of $M$ are the same as those of $A$, with an additional $m + 1$ repetitions of $q$; each eigenvalue $\lambda$ has a one-dimensional eigenspace, spanned by $(1, \lambda, \dots, \lambda^{n - 1}, p(\lambda), \lambda p(\lambda), \dots, \lambda^m p(\lambda))$.
   - Every Jordan chain for $A$, namely, vectors $\vec{v}_i$ associated with an eigenvalue $\lambda$ such that $(A - \lambda I) \vec{v}_i = \vec{v}_{i - 1}$, upgrades to vectors $\vec{u}_i$ with the same property for $M$, by attaching $m + 1$ zeros to the end.

   It follows that $M$ has a generalized eigenbasis consisting of upgrades of a generalized eigenbasis for $A$, together with $m + 1$ additional generalized eigenvectors filling out a Jordan chain of length $k + m + 1$ for eigenvalue $q$.
3. A generalized eigenvector $\vec{v}_h$ of eigenvalue $\lambda$ at the top of a Jordan chain produces a fundamental solution to $\vec{z}' = M\vec{z}$ via the matrix exponential:
   $$e^{\lambda t} \sum_{i = 0}^{h - 1} \frac{1}{i!} t^i \vec{v}_{h - i}.$$
   The general solution is therefore the general linear combination of these.  Taking the first components (which we may assume are nonzero only for the eigenvectors (indexed $\vec{v}_1$ in the above sum)), we get a solution of $Lx = y$.  The terms coming from "upgrades" are part of the homogeneous solution to $Lx = 0$, and the remaining terms are some linear combination of $t^k e^{qt}, \dots, t^{k + m} e^{qt}$, as claimed.

Comment: Is homogeneous case covered before this? Then the "Method of annihilators" works too. 

Comment: It is, but I don't know that term.  I'm not really asking for a suggestion "what's the best proof of undetermined coefficients?"; I gave two others previously in the course.  I was testing out this one, which is (in my opinion) a great advertisement for almost every technique and idea introduced to attack linear equations.

Comment: I see. BTW, that term "Method of annihilators" is: Further applying differential operator to make the nonhomogeneous term disappear. I like your proof here though. 

Comment: Ah.  I think that boils down to Terry Tao's proof, then.

Comment: Basically, it is the same line with your proof, but instead solving the homogeneous equation $(D-q)^{m+1}L=0$. 

Answer (score 16):

1. If $L$ has characteristic polynomial $\lambda \mapsto p(\lambda)$, then the conjugated differential operator $e^{-qt} L e^{qt}$ has characteristic polynomial $\lambda \mapsto p(\lambda+q)$.  From this we may easily reduce the problem to the $q=0$ case.
2. If the characteristic polynomial $\lambda \mapsto p(\lambda)$ of $L$ has a zero of order $k$ at the origin, then $p$ factors as $p(\lambda) = \tilde p(\lambda) \lambda^k$, and $L$ similarly factors as $L = \tilde L \frac{d}{dt^k}$.  Since every degree $m$ polynomial has a $k$-fold antiderivative that is equal to $t^k$ times a degree $m$ polynomial, we can thus reduce the problem to the $q=0, k=0$ case.
3. If $q=0$ and $k=0$, then $p(0)$ is non-vanishing; by rescaling we may take $p(0)=1$.  Then $p(\lambda) = 1 + \lambda r(\lambda)$ for some polynomial $r$, so $L = 1 + R \frac{d}{dt}$ for some differential operator $R$.  On the finite dimensional vector space spanned by $1,t,\ldots,t^m$, the operator $R \frac{d}{dt}$ acts nilpotently (as it always reduces the degree) and so $L$ is unipotent, hence invertible (by Neumann series), in this space, and the claim follows.

Comment: This is a very nice, not at all messy "proof by integration", but I was more asking for a reference to the argument I gave.  Or, can I consider this post an earliest reference to the proof you give? :)

Comment: I was about to post a reference to *my* favorite proof of this, but then I read the question, so I did not.  Like Terry, I do not find the "matrix" method easiest to understand.  But that is just my background, I am sure.

Comment: @Gerald: I'm curious about your favorite proof, so perhaps you could give the link in a comment?

Comment: I cannot find the book at the moment, but as I recall: *An Introduction to Ordinary Differential Equations,*  by Earl A. Coddington; Section 12, Theorem 22.

Comment: Oh, I have that book.  I'll go check.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Ryan and everybody,

Besides the very beautiful proof by Tao, a very nice and easy linear algebra approach to the undetermined coefficients method can be found in C. C. Ross ``Why the method of undetermined coefficients works'', Am. Math. Monthly 98 (1991), pp. 747-749.

I also suggest R. C. Gupta ``Linear differential equations with constant coefficients: a recursive alternative to the method of the undetermined coefficients'', Int. J. Math. Educ. Sci. Technol. 27 (1996), pp. 757-760.

A very easy formula (quite good for the students) that gives a particular solution of the equation $$L(\frac{d}{dt})y=t^m e^{q t}, \ q \in \mathbb C,$$ 
where $L$ is a nth order linear differential operator with constant coefficients, can be found in O. R. B. de Oliveira ``A formula substituting the undetermined coefficients and the annihilator methods'', Int. J. Math. Educ. Sci. Technol. 44 (3), 2013, pp. 462-468, http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/0020739X.2012.714496. The proof of the formula is in p. 465 and it is short and very elementary.

The idea is the following: the given ode has a particular solution $y=f(t)e^{q t}$ where $f$ is a polynomial that satisfies the following ode with constant coefficients
$$\frac{p^{(n)}(q)}{n!}f^{(n)} + \cdots + \frac{p'(q)}{1!}f' + \frac{p(q)}{0!}f= t^m,$$
where $p=p(\lambda)$ is the characteristic polynomial associated to $L$. The short and elementary proof of this formula, with some examples, is over there. Using it, we find a particular solution through solving a triangular linear system.

The same formula shows that if $q$ is a root of multiplicity $k$ of $p(\lambda)=0$ then $e^{qt},\ldots, t^{k-1}e^{qt}$ are solutions of the homogeneous equation $Ly=0$, since we have $p(q)=\cdots=p^{(k-1)}(q)=0$ and $\frac{d^l}{dt^l}(t^j)=0$ if $l>j$. Furthermore, in this case the formula boils down to
$$\frac{p^{(n)}(q)}{n!}f^{(n)} + \cdots + \frac{p^{(k)}(q)}{k!}f^{(k)} = t^m,$$
which shows that $f^{(k)}$ is a polynomial of order $m$. Integrating it $k$-times we are able to choose $f(t)=t^kg(t)$, where $g$ is a polynomial of order $m$.

Oswaldo R. B. de Oliveira